# Displaying dicom datatset using VTK

Tags: vtk, dicom

I want to process a dicom dataset and display it using VTK.
How can i know in advance if the graphic card will be able to display the volume?

i've tried using glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE_EXT,size) that gives you the maximum number of texels that can be rendered using the graphic card, and then try to compare it with the output of m_vtkImageReader->GetOutput()->GetDimensions(dimensions). i thought that if dimensions.x*dimensions.y*dimensions.z > size then the vtk will throw an error, but it didn't happened.

I'll be glad to hear about other ways, or maybe someone can point me were i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VTK provide gpu-based volume processing, and non gpu. You may try to use VtkSmartVolumeMapper. This mapper select best mapper, from vtk mappers, for your card. It is display volume fine with notebook via unichrome videocard with 32 mb of memory.